# popToViewController presenting a black view

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have an app that has many different views. The entry point to the app is the home page where I have 2 buttons (note that the home page is embedded in a navigation controller). Each button leads to a new stack of views, I tried embedding the first view of those stacks into a navigation controller, but when I push a button on the home page that leads to a new stack, the app crashes giving me a "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'" message. So I avoided embedding the stacks into a nav controller. The problem happens when I push the save button in the last view of the stack. In there I did the usual

```
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
```

This does not work and I get sent to the firstViewController, however the navigation bar buttons don't show up, the background is black and nothing shows. If I popToRootViewController however, it works. Cheers!

Comment: It might be interesting to know whether `firstViewController` is in `self.navigationController`'s `viewControllers` array.

Comment: I honestly do not know, I started development not too long ago so I'm not an expert yet, but I found a solution that works. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got something working.  (If you were curious about what was wrong before, using the debugger or NSLog to look at the things I mentioned in my comment could have discovered the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Alright well I feel stupid now, I realized that the segues between my buttons and view controllers were push segues. Now I embedded the first view controller of both stacks in a navigation controller, and changed my segues into modal segues. By doing that I was able to use popToRootViewController instead of popToView Controller... Now my save button leads back to the view controller I wanted to show, everything works fine.